# Java: how to return string before char

Tags: java, string

I have the following string

```
String name = "John - Paul"
```

So what i want to do is retrieve `John` (all before the `-`). This is what i am trying but i cannot retrieve from before the `-` only after

```
String parseName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" - ", -1), name.indexOf(" - ", 0));
```

How do you do this and can someone explain as well please (note: i do not want to use regex)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing your starting and ending indices - you need to take a substring from the first character (index=0) up to the index of `" - "` :

```
String parseName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" - "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the String.substring method are beginning and end of the string. So when the first one is 0, you are selecting from the beginning.

```
String parseName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" - "));
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your comment of *(note: i do not want to use regex)*, but I would still write this using split() - despite the fact it takes a regex string as its argument - because this is what it is for.

```java
String name = "John - Paul";
String firstName = name.split(" - ")[0];
```

And, in this case, the regex is no more complex than the argument to indexOf().

The answers using substring() are still completely valid.